# gtssummary, Despite providing grouping variable there is an error message with paired tests. There may only be one observation per group

Tags: r, gtsummary

I found a problem that I can't resolve in gtsummary R package. I am getting error regarding paired test(s). Similar issue was already reported but there was a group variable missing in the code. I specified gruop variable, nonetheless I still get the same error message:"There may only be one observation per group= per by= level - problem"

```
    install.packages("gtsummary")
    library(gtsummary)
    data(lalonde)
    variables <- lalonde%>% select(age,treat)
    table1 <-
    tbl_summary(
    variables,
    by = treat, # split table by group
    statistic = list(all_continuous() ~ "{mean} ({sd})"),
    digits = all_continuous() ~ 2,
    missing_text = "(Missing)") %>%
    add_n() %>%
    add_p(list(all_continuous() ~         
    "paired.t.test"),group="treat") %>%
    modify_header(label = "Treatment") %>% # update the         
    column header
    bold_labels()
```

I get the following message:

Error: 'age': There may only be one observation per group= per by= level.

I dont if it is a bug or I am doing sth wrong. I would be most grateful if someone could look at it.
Thank you

Comment: The error message seems pretty clear. But if you'd like further assistance, you'll need to update your post with a minimal reproducible example (aka a reprex).

Comment: Thank you. I corrected it. Congratulations on the package you developed.
Best regards
Tadeusz

Comment: 1. Can you tell me where the lalonde data comes from? 2. Please include code for how you would calculate a paired t test using this data

Answer (score 0):

Thank you once again for package gtsummary and all the effort it took you to prepare it. I am sending code. Lalonde data come form matchIT package, they are not trial data therefore groups of course need to be matched. (the was why I needed tests for paired data in the first place)

```
install.packages(c("gtsummary","MatchIt","tidyverse"))
library(MatchIt)
library(gtsummary)
library(tidyverse)

data(lalonde)
m.out <- matchit(treat ~ age + educ + race + nodegree +
                married + re74 + re75, data = lalonde)

data<-match.data(m.out, group="all")

data_paired <-
data %>%
select(age, treat) %>%
group_by(treat) %>%
mutate(id = row_number())

data_paired %>%
group_by(id) %>%
filter(n() == 2) %>%
ungroup() %>%

tbl_summary(by = treat, include = -id,statistic =   
list(all_continuous() ~ "{mean} ({sd})")) %>%
add_p(test = list(all_continuous() ~ "paired.t.test"), 
     group = id)
```

The one thing as I find slightly misleading that "group" is "id" not "treat". I should read your tutorial in the first place.

Best regards
T.

Comment: Hi Tadeusz. Please don't post additional code as an answer to the question - answers are only for answering questions. You should **edit** your original question to contain this code, and delete this "answer". Thank you.